# Unable to get millisecond reading for gunicorn access log response time

Tags: python, gunicorn

I have altered gunicorn_config.py to have:

```
access_log_format = '%(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s" %(T)s %(M)s %(D)s %(L)s'
```

`T` request time in seconds,
`M` request time in milliseconds,
`D` request time in microseconds,
`L` request time in decimal seconds

I want the response time.

I tested, and here is the output that I get

```
<ip> - - [19/Aug/2020:06:11:04 CDT] "DELETE /ws/v1/sessions HTTP/1.1" 200 139 "-" "python-requests/2.22.0" 0 - 13127 0.013127
<ip> - - [19/Aug/2020:06:11:12 CDT] "POST /ws/v1/sessions?userId=<name> HTTP/1.1" 200 928 "-" "python-requests/2.22.0" 0 - 36    518 0.036518
```

In the last part of the lines (say, `0 - 13127 0.013127`), why does the millisecond reading give a "-"? I could not find out anything from the [documentation](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#access-log-format). I am a novice to both gunicorn and python. Please help. Gunicorn version is 19.7.1, python3.4

Answer (score 2):

Checked from gunicorn/config.py and gunicorn/glogging.py that millisecond is not implemented in the gunicorn version that I use.